# No sound from UDA1334 PCM DAC on Compute Module 4 with 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS

Tags: audio, i2s, compute-module-4, phat-dac

So I am trying to verify that two PCM devices I have work one is a UDA1334 and the other a microphone. So I installed the latest 64 bit Raspberry Pi OS and enabled I2S and the hifiberry-dac overlay.

I followed the instructions at the two links the first link is based on the second but both have good info. I also attached a screenshot of the output from the command aplay -L and the sound card in alsamixer. It appears that the DAC device is showing up.

In that Adafruit tutorial in the asounds.conf file it has lines that say "type hw card 0" I changed these to "type hw card 1" and then the DAC device seemed to appear as an audio device I could select on the desktop tray. If I left it at 0 nothing ever appeared anywhere.

However AlsaMixer doesn't show this device by default it shows PulseAudio.

I am not sure what else I can try, I attempted to remove PulseAudio and that didn't seem to work. I also messed around with the alsa config files and managed to change my DAC to be the primary device but I don't know if I did it properly. There was no sound at all.

So I am at a loss of what to try next. I'm just not getting any sound at all. If I changed the sound to output over the HDMI audio output then it works but not using the DAC.

I tried using the speaker-test -c2 command and also playing YouTube videos and neither produced any sound.

Any ideas on what I could try next?

[Adafruit Stereo DAC UDA144](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-i2s-stereo-decoder-uda1334a/raspberry-pi-usage)

[PhatDAC Pimoroni](https://learn.pimoroni.com/article/raspberry-pi-phat-dac-install)

[image: Terminal Output]

[image: AlsaMixer new DAC device that I added]

[image: AlsaMixer Default Device]

Comment: Raspberry Pi OS now uses Pulse Audio rather than ALSA raspberrypi.org/blog/new-raspberry-pi-os-release-december-2020 The tutorials you followed are obsolete.